# why asp button and html button giving different results?

Tags: css, asp.net

[image: heres the picture to all the code result]

I have given same class to both asp button and html button but its giving different result. asp button is creating i tag and all classes is given to that, not to the input (text="submit") tag

Comment: asp button is rendered as `input type="submit"`

Comment: i know what asp button and html button does. i am asking about the design. why asp button giving that f ugly button

Comment: `<button>` and `<input type="submit" />` have different css styles applied by default. You will need to "normalize" them to look same.

Comment: ok now i get it. Thanks @Morpheus